# How to create a Regex doing a exact match?

Tags: python

I have the following two inputs `input1` and `input2` ,both the inputs are matching the `train` variable,the regex should only match `input2` as it has the exact train name "Glory" ,regex should an exact match of the train, how to fix this?

```
import re
input1="""Sun Jul  1 17:42:38 2018 username1 <usernam1@company.com> forwarded CoreCapture-275.3 to GloryB and GloryE"""

input2 = "Wed Mar 21 16:04:59 2018 username2 <username2@company.com> submitted CoreCapture-275 to Glory"

train = "Glory"
for line in reversed(input1.splitlines()) :
    match = re.match(r'.*(submitted|forwarded)(.*) to .*%s.*'%train,line)
    if match:
        print line
        print match.group(2).strip()
        break
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
should not match input1
CoreCapture-275(for input2)
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [`*?`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)?

Comment: @abarnert - No,even after adding `*?` regex still matches input1,it should not match input1 at all

Comment: @abarnert - I want to do an exact match of Glory in the line , it should not match a line with `GloryB` ,`GloryE` ,It the line contains Glory GloryB GloryE,it should still match

Comment: You still haven't explained what "exact match" means. Why is `to Glory` an exact match, but `to GloryB` not? Is it about word boundaries? End of the line? Something different? I posted an answer with a guess, but it's just a guess, because I don't actually know what rule you're trying to apply here.

Comment: @abarnert - GloryB and Glory are different words, so it is word boundaries

Comment: If that's what you mean (and if you're happy with the `re` definition of "word characters") then my answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess at what you want, but I could be wrong.

You're asking for `.*Glory.*`—that is, any string that includes the substring `Glory`. Greediness isn't going to change the fact that `' to GloryB and GloryE'` contains that substring. It *could* change whether you match `''`, `'Glory'`, `'B and GloryE'` or `'GloryB and '`, `'Glory'`, `'E'`, but that doesn't do any good; either way, it matches.

I think what you *may* want to ask for is `.*\bGlory\b.*`—that is, any string that contains the substring `Glory` between word boundaries. [Like this Regex101 demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/mARBy5/1):

```
match = re.match(r'.*(submitted|forwarded)(.*) to .*\b%s\b.*'%train,line)
```

See [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for an explanation of what `\b` means:

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that formally, `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning/end of the string. This means that `r'\bfoo\b'` matches `'foo'`, `'foo.'`, `'(foo)'`, `'bar foo baz'` but not `'foobar'` or `'foo3'`.

If you wanted to match only `Glory` at the end of the line, or `Glory` with whitespace (rather than any non-word character) or EoL, or something else, then of course this is wrong.